# I couldn't able to create ubuntu bionic 64 server in vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, server, vagrant

I am learning GitHub and remote server base development of projects. So while doing so, I came up with this error which I could not able to solve. I also searched google. Since I couldn't able to solve this or understand this error by myself. I am posting this question here.
Please help me fix it.
I am trying this in windows 10
here is my vagrant file code

" # -*- mode: ruby -*-

```
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure

# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for

# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what

# you're doing.

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.

# For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at

# https://docs.vagrantup.com.


# Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for

# boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  
  config.vm.box_version = "~> 20200304.0.0"


  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000


  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

  systemctl disable apt-daily.service

  systemctl disable apt-daily.timer

  

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv zip

  touch /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases

  if ! grep -q PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases; then
 
  echo "# PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
 
  echo "alias python='python3'" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases

 fi

SHELL

end"
```

here is my error
"
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

```
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/bionic64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

default: Box Provider: virtualbox

default: Box Version: ~> 20200304.0.0

The box 'ubuntu/bionic64' could not be found or

could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private

box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via

`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded

URL and error message are shown below:



URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/bionic64"]

Error: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The 

revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate."
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message, it seems you are trying to download a not more public box

From the official documentation you can try with `hashincorp/bionic64`
here link to documentation: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes#official-boxes

Comment: Actually ubuntu/bionic64 is public box its not private box,i tried it in Linux system today and it worked fine in Linux. But in windows i am still  facing same problem . Don't know why please help me with it